# Passing template into boost function

Tags: c++, function, boost, templates

```
template <class EventType>
class IEvent;

class IEventable;

typedef boost::function<void (IEventable&, IEvent&)> behaviorRef;
```

What is the right way for passing template class IEvent into boost function? With this code I get:
`error: functional cast expression list treated as compound expression
error: template argument 1 is invalid
error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::function` needs a *type*, so you cannot pass it a *template*'s name, it has to be a template *instance*. So either use a specific instance

```
typedef boost::function<void (IEventable&, IEvent<SomeEventType>&)> behaviorRef;
```

or put the whole thing itself into a template:

```
template< typename EventType >
struct foo {
  typedef boost::function<void (IEventable&, IEvent<EventType >&)> behaviorRef;
};
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample?

Comment: Yes, second code sample (about structure) is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A class template is just a template for a class, it's not a real class yet. You need to specify the template parameters to get a class out of it, for example `IEvent<int>`. So you need to decide for which kind of events you want that typedef to be, for example for int:

```
typedef boost::function<void (IEventable&, IEvent<int>&)> behaviorRef;
```

Otherwise, if you want a typedef for all possible template instantiations, you need to put the typedef itself into another templated class. See sbi's answer for an example of that.

Comment: Actually it's called "class template" (not "template class") - and that's, as you wrote, because it is indeed a _template_, not a _class_.